# Who are the 5 consultants who got the $700-800 million from the DNC / Joint Fundraising Agreement Budget?

Tags: united-states, dnc

On the public meeting of the [DNC Unity Reform commission](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wh1EGReFg74) Nomiki Konst said:

> We are talking about close to 700-800 million dollars between the Joint Fundraising Agreement and the DNC being spent on five consultants

Who are those five consultants?

Comment: Not an answer, but hopefully helpful to someone who is researching an answer more than me:  MotherJones published the memo that memorializes the Joint Fundraising Agreement, and they aren't mentioned there.  [Source](http://www.motherjones.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/blog_hillary_dnc_victory_fund_agreement.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Via Our Revolution CCC twitter @pausetheprocess  — [link](https://twitter.com/pausetheprocess/status/940112499159941121)

> "They win even when Democrats lose:
>
> - GMMB Consultants - AJ Lenar
> - Precision Strategies -  Jennifer O'Malley Dillon
> - The Podesta Group - Tony & John
> - SKDK NickerBocker - Anita Dunn, Hillary Rosen
> - Benenson Strategy Group - Joel Benenson
> - Perkins Coie Law International - Marc Elias"
>
> "I should include Raelynn Olson to GMMB Consultants.  Olson has other consultant firms under various names, tries to keep a low profile." — [link](https://twitter.com/pausetheprocess/status/940113562533367809)