# Why is there no public outcry when the DNC gives control of a large part of their money to lobbyists?

Tags: united-states, dnc

In the news there has been a lot of talk about how campaign finance is bad because it allows lobbyists to give money to political parties to buy access. [Nomiki Konst](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wh1EGReFg74) held a fiery speech about how a large chunks of the money of the DNC goes to five consultants. In a previous [question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/26883/1483) I asked about the identity of those consultants.

It seems it goes to people who say on their website things [like](https://www.podesta.com/):

> Tony does more than talk on behalf of clients – he leverages what
>   POLITICO calls an “in-the-trenches sensibility” to offer expert
>   tactical guidance informed by decades of legislative, political and
>   public relations experience. Tony has been distinguished by The Wall
>   Street Journal, the Financial Times, The New York Times, GQ, Newsweek
>   and Bloomberg Businessweek, among other publications both inside and
>   outside the Beltway, as a leading lobbyist in Washington today.

As a German, it seems to be very strange to not give control of huge sums of campaign money to local parties but to self professed "leading lobbyist" who also takes money from corporations to advocate the agenda of those corporations.

Why isn't there public outcry in the US?

Comment: You mean public out cry as in people marching in the streets or outcry like news networks because there was a lot of out cry coming from conservative networks like Fox.

Comment: @Noah If I search the website of Fox news than it doesn't have a single story about Nomiki Konst calling the DNC funding practices corrupt at the DNC Unity Commission. There also isn't a single Fox news story that mentions the Benenson Strategy Group.

Comment: What is the German system like?  That might be helpful for understanding why your expectation is not met.

Comment: @indigochild : In Germany local parties are generally strong compared to US local political parties.

Comment: @Christian, here you go: [Nomiki calling DNC practices corrupt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UGpMCs7ZAi0) hope that helps. Lobbyist have become almost a norm in US politics. They are in every fabric of the political system both Democrat and Republicans.

Comment: @Noah : You are linking to a C-SPAN video with 2,205 views. That's supposed to be a representation of out cry?

Comment: Outcry from whom? BE MORE SPECIFIC on who is suppose to be "out-crying"

Comment: @Noah : Do you think the phrase "public outcry" is meaningless? Above you claimed that outcry from Fox news happens but when I google the relevant terms that's not the case. Why doesn't the outcry you claimed to exist exist in reality?

Comment: Possibly there's no great outcry because a lot of Americans think it's their money (voluntarily given to the DNC by supporters), so they should be able to do what they want with it.  As an American, it would seem strange for the DNC to give lots of money to local parties.

Comment: @jamesqf : It isn't exactly money flowing where "the DNC" wants it. The DNC chair got kept out of the loop of how the money was spent.

Comment: This is how American politics works (or doesn’t work, depending on your view)

Answer (score -1):

If you donate enough money to the campaigns of US politicians, you can expect legislation in your favor.[The Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2013/11/does-more-campaign-money-actually-buy-more-votes-investigation/355154/) & [WaPo](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/1999/05/07/microsofts-window-of-influence/424f0b28-e86c-42cf-a4c8-cb2db173715d/?utm_term=.dda304f0af73)  But why aren't more people outraged with this money buying influence?  I think it boils down to a few reasons.

This practice is just opaque enough to not attract people's attention.  Few politicians campaign on changing it and most argue they still vote independent of donations (which has been shown to be false), see first footnote.  Until a big scandal breaks that shows the true corruption of this system, we may not see change.

Secondly, we are easily distracted.  We are enraged by abortion or gun rights or other issues that have significantly less impact on us.  I suspect politicians relish having such issues to distract us from the legal bribery.

Third, is complexity.  It's not always easy to explain how campaign contributions affect voting.  Thus, if less people understand it or see it, the fewer will be upset about it.

Comment: I'm ok with the down votes, but please explain why.

Comment: I don't think most people find it "sickening".  They only object when the legislation is something they don't want.  E.g. if someone with a few billion bribed enough legislators to say end the "War on Drugs" or rein in the police, I'd be estatic.

Comment: This case isn't about the effects of donations. The money that the Benenson Strategy Group receives from Walmart, Bank of America and Chase is a direct payment for lobbying. The case is not Benenson Strategy Group paying money to the DNC for getting political favors but the DNC paying money to the Benenson Strategy Group.

Comment: @jamesqf, I agree actually.  People miss what's going on in it's entirety.  The problem isn't that one bill they disagree with.  It's that it came about due to campaign contributions.  This disconnect is why the problem persists.

Comment: @Christian, fair enough.  I was trying to get to what I thought his greater question was, especially based on the second to last paragraph.  My answer may be off topic, as it doesn't answer his specific question, but I'll leave it for posterity.

Comment: This is nothing more than a rant and does not answer the OP question.

Comment: This answer would be better if it were backed up.  Being backed up is one of the tools for showing that an answer is factually true, rather than speculation or your opinion.

Comment: Why would anyone donate to any campaign if they didn't expect the result to be legislation in their favor?  And why would you think that abortion or gun rights issues don't have significant, immediate impacts on people?

Comment: Most low level donators don't expect legislation. They are merely supporting a candidate they like. My point is not that these issues won't affect people, but that they are blown out of proportion and a quick, passionate dichotomy forms around them. Often the bill in question is of little consequence, or there is no bill at all.  The passion around these issues can cause single issue voters and it's all a huge distraction from other issues that have direct effect, such as the money is politics.

Answer (score -2):

The DNC is not part of the government; it is a private organization, protected by the 1st Amendment Right of Free Association (the ability to form a club or organization with whatever like-minded individuals you deem fit).

Why should the public care about how the DNC spends money?

Should the public care about how every Gardening Club and Bowling Team spends money?  While the DNC is larger and better organized than a Gardening Club, and is politically motivated, it is structurally no different:  It is a political club formed to do politics as they see best, including hiring whomever they want.